# "I got to shoot a few animals" - kill or take a picture?

Tags: verbs, ambiguity

I wanted to say that I had managed to take a few pictures of some animals. But when I say "I got to shoot a few animals", is that clear? As shooting animals to me sounds more like killing..

Comment: If there are more sentences before or after this one, then it might be disambiguated a bit better. By itself, I would say it is ambiguous.

Comment: Are you a [dentist](http://metro.co.uk/2015/07/31/dentist-who-shot-cecil-the-lion-wanted-to-shoot-a-very-big-elephant-as-well-5320734/) by any chance? If not, people will naturally assume you are referring to taking photos.

Comment: You could use **snap** instead -  people are not likely to assume you intend to break animals into pieces!

Comment: It is ambiguous.  Many stories/jokes revolve around this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

To me, without context, the statement is not clear.

Here is the [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoot) of the verb *shoot*:

> 1 . (transitive) To fire (a weapon that releases a projectile).
>
> 9 . (transitive, analogous) To photograph.

If I meant the second definition, I would rephrase the sentence. For example:

> I got to photograph a few animals.

Comment: Yes. And having established that you were involved in photography it would be alright to say *I managed to shoot a few pictures*. I would however hesitate at any point to say *I shot some animals*!

Comment: @WS2 Your comment deserves to be an answer of its own. The object of the "photography" sense of "shoot" is the photograph itself not the person/animal/view depicted

Comment: @IanF1 That's not always true. Sometimes the photographer _is_ shooting the subject (see definition #9 above). Example: "The photographer shot my friends at the party."